# Gradle NPM node error (npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm

How does gradle recognize npm commands?

I am getting this exception from gradle build task

```
npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Preconditions:

I have installed node locally on a windows machine.
NPM command is working through the command line, but while running gradle build file from command or IDE I am getting that exception.

Comment: I updated my build process task to  have below statements to run successful build .                                                 if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine = ["cmd", "/c", "npm", "install"]
    } else {
        commandLine = ["npm", "install"]
    }

Comment: [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) might be worth a look. It manages its own Node install, so removes the requirement to have it pre-installed (and avoids having to deal with OS differences yourself).

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify you have npm installed (it should live in your nodejs program folder)
2. If you don't find a file called "npm" in there, (re)install node by downloading and running the nodejs `msi` file (npm comes with it)
3. Add your node.js's program folder to your systems path and restart your command line.

Comment: Thanks SamT. As i earlier mentioned ,NPM command is working on my command prompt, but its not recognizable from build script (gradle).

Answer (score 0):

When you run gradle from your IDE, you are using a different path than when you run it from the command line. If you run the gradle task with --stacktrace and --debug, it should output the path it is using. You will need to set the path for your IDE according to OS/IDE instructions.